# active not working in bootstrap 4 tabs

Tags: html, css, tabs

i m using bootstrap 4 tabs/pills code from w3school.
But i am facing problem. like when i am clicking on any link active not changing it is static on 1st link

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs control-btn">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz01" class="btn btn-info" role="button">01</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz02" class="btn btn-info" role="button">02</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz03" class="btn btn-info" role="button">03</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz04" class="btn btn-info" role="button">04</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz05" class="btn btn-info" role="button">05</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz06" class="btn btn-info" role="button">06</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz07" class="btn btn-info" role="button">07</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz08" class="btn btn-info" role="button">08</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz09" class="btn btn-info" role="button">09</a></li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#quiz10" class="btn btn-info" role="button">10</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
                  <div id="quiz01" class="tab-pane fade-in active">
                    <h3>Question 01.</h3>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry,
                      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry?
                    </p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="value01" value="01"> <b>1.</b>Option one</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="value01" value="02"> <b>2.</b>Option Two</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="value01" value="03"> <b>3.</b>Option Three</p>
                    <p><input type="radio" name="value01" value="04"> <b>4.</b>Option Four</p>
                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <a class="btn btn-success btnNext">Save & Next</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: of course....`class="active"` is only to the first you have to write JS or Jquery code to change the class when click

Comment: Here s the answer https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_active_element

Comment: but when i am checking it in other site it working perfectly

Comment: If this are tabs, do the elements they should toggle exist (like `#quiz02`)? Bootstrap should take care of the `.active` class toggle when the element is used correctly

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h check

Comment: And the first toggle is still `data-toggle="pill"` instead of `data-toggle="tab"`

Comment: hey Brainfeeder tab on click working but active class not changing

Comment: yeah that was my mistake but still not working

Comment: @VikashSDNT do you try to change it.. it doesn't happen automaticlly

Comment: i am using bs4 but this code is from bootstrap older version.

Comment: help me please.

Answer (score 1):

I got and idea from my friend.
Actually this not working on bootstrap4.

so i did add this code inside script

```
 $(".nav-tabs li a").click(function(){
      $(".nav-tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).parent().addClass("active");
 });
```

And now it is working.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tabbed navigation requires Jquery to work, and needs to be included in the head of your page. I used jQuery 3.2.1 slim minified. If you add Jquery to your header and follow this code pattern using Aria it will work.

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" 
      href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria- 
      selected="true">Home</a>

    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" 
    href="#nav-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-profile" aria- 
    selected="false">Profile</a>

    <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" 
     href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria- 
      selected="false">Contact</a>
 </div>
</nav>
 <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
   <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria- 
    labelledby="nav-home-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria- 
     labelledby="nav-profile-tab">...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-contact" role="tabpanel" aria- 
    labelledby="nav-contact-tab">...</div>
 </div>
```